# Work with appended audio

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio

i have trouble with appended audio.
when page is scrolling i'm dynamicly load an audio, but then, when i'm trying to play it, div, in which located audiofile isn't changing it's property, how to solve that?
How i appending:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
            if(scrollCount == 0){
                if($(window).scrollTop() > 200){
                    AddMoreContent();
                }
            } else{
                if($(window).scrollTop() > $(window).height() * scrollCount - 100) {
                    AddMoreContent();
                }
            }
        });  

     function AddMoreContent(){
         $.ajax({url:thisPage + "/" + thisPage + "." + scrollCount +".html",context: document.body, success: function(response){
                $("#main-content").append(response);
             scrollCount++;
         }
        });
     }
```

How i listening audio event:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("audio").on("play", function () {
            var _this = $(this);
            //$("audio").each(function (i, el) {
            //    if (!$(el).is(_this))
            //        $(el).get(0).pause();
            //    $(el).parent().removeClass("intro");
            //});
            _this.parent().addClass("intro");
          });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [play event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/play) does not bubble, So you can't use event delegation. You need to bind the handler once the element is added to the dom so

```
function AddMoreContent() {
    $.ajax({
        url: thisPage + "/" + thisPage + "." + scrollCount + ".html",
        context: document.body,
        success: function (response) {
            var $els  = $(response);
            $("#main-content").append($els);
            //use .filter if the audio elements are in the root level of response
            $els.find("audio").on('play', function () {
                //do your stuff
            });
            scrollCount++;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: and one more question, how to play that appended audio?

Comment: sorry.. what do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `audio` elements are appended through the `$.ajax` requests, you need to use a delegated event handler:

```
$('#main-content').on('play', 'audio', function() {
    $(this).parent().addClass('intro');
    // your code here...
});
```